# How to pass integer as unsigned parameter in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, parameters, unsigned

I'm using a library call, `setInstance(ByVal instance As UInteger)`, in my [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) code. The parameter I need to pass is an `Integer`. Is there anything I need to do to convert the integer parameter to an unsigned integer? The number is guaranteed to be positive and less than 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like so...

```
Dim MyInt As Int32 = 10
Dim MyUInt As UInt32 = CUInt(MyInt)
setInstance(MyUInt)
```

Answer (score 3):

CUInt or CType(x, UInt) allow converting a **positive integer**.

It throws an exception when x is negative.

To use Int as Uint, you can use some tricks:

```
  dim bb() = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(myInt)
  dim MyUint = System.BitConverter.ToUInt32(bb, 0)
```

Also with System.Buffer.BlockCopy for arrays.

If you configure the compiler to disable *Check Integer Overflow* (default for C#). Then you can use **CUInt** with negative values with no check - not exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `CUint` to convert a variable to a `UInteger`.

Comment: As answer to values above zero ok. But have you tried to CUInt() or DirectCast(value,UInt32) a negative integer to UInt32 (eg. -460819684)? Very easy in C# but completely unintuitive VB.Net.